# Android: сменить title не из класса-активности

Tags: java

Унаследовал `MainActivity` от некоторой `BasicActivity` во избежания повторения кода в новых активностях-наследниках. В `BasicActivity` сделал public-метод для изменения заголовка, что отображается в toolbar:

```
public class BasicActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    // ...

    protected void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    public void changeToolbarTitle(String title){
        toolbar.setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Из `MainActivity`, а вернее из `onCreate()`, этот метод можно легко вызвать:

```
changeToolbarTitle("test");
```

Но как то же самое сделать из других классов, не являющихся Activity (например, из наследника `Fragment`)? Я пробовал:

```
MainActivity.this.changeToolbarTitle("Test");
```

Comment: `getActivity().changeToolbarTitle("Test");` ?

Comment: Нет, будет `Cannot resolve method`, если из `onCreateView` фрагмента вызывать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У фрагмента есть метод `getActivity()`, который вернет `Activity`. Если твой фрагмент привязан именно к `BasicActivity`, то результат метода легко скастуется к этому классу:

```
BasicActivity activity = (BasicActivity)getActivity();
```

тогда можно сменить тайтл прямо из фрагмента:

```
activity.changeToolbarTitle("lol")
```

Этот способ небезопасен тем, что фрагмент может быть расположен в любой активити. Таким образом, нет гарантии, что `getActivity()` вернет такой резульатат, который спокойно скастуется без `ClassCastException`. Поэтому советую тебе сделать некий `BasicFragment`, у которого будет метод:

```
public BasicActivity getBaseActivity() {
    return (BasicActivity)getActivity();
}
```

А в самом приложении взять за правило использовать только наследники `BasicActivity` и `BasicFragment`

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Всё работает.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu если ответ вам помог, отметьте его решением.